Creating a mylar rain curtain/drape animation in Blender
For a stage production I'm trying to create this kind of mylar rain curtain

On the stage they tend to go up and come down on on wires. I also want to implement this in my animation, and let a character come through the strings at some point.
Because they're extremely light they tend to float a little whilst coming up an down. I want to be able to create this effect.
I tried multiple times already, the first time didn't work at all. Second time, the mesh was OK, but because all the strings are a little apart from each other, there was no friction, and  going up and down also didn't have any impact on the strings wind wise, so they looked stiff and didn't move at all.
What I'm trying to create

Hello, have you tried a Cloth simulation and what does it give?

Hi moonboots, thanks for your quick reply. The first time the cloth simulation exploded. The second time the cloth simulation went fairly smooth, but as I've written in the post above already, there was no movement at all in the strings.. very stiff

are you looking for something like that? https://zupimages.net/up/24/25/dsi3.gif

Yes exactly! The height is somewhat perfect, the widt of the curtain is much longer

You can do it with a Cloth simulation. First create a plane, subidivide it, select all its vertical edges and rip (V):

In Weight Paint mode create a vertex group at the top with the Gradient brush:

Give a Cloth simulation to the plane, choose the vertex group as Pin Group, also enable the Self Collisions option:

Create some Force Fields like Wind or Turbulence to create agitation:


Thank you. This way doesn't in become one nig cloth, how did you make the seperate strings?

*big sorry typed too fast

O get it now, select rip creates the string

yes, select the vertical edges and press V to rip and create the strips

Hi, this also happened the first time I tried to do it.

What does it mean when it does this? Is it too dense?

could you please share your file?

I accidentely forgot to save, So I made it again and it worked! Thanks to your help.

The only thing now is, for the past hour I've been trying to add a wind force field, cause it's lacking natural movement. It's inside the theatre, so there's no wind force, but still should be moving more than what's happening now.. It's my first time adding a force field, it seems like the cloth should react automatically to it, but it doesn't seem to react to the forcefield.

Im trying to upload the blender file, but it's 600+ mb, I don't know why it's that big.... My wifi's terrible, so the uploading of the file isn't really working

btw, I think it didnt work the past few times because I probably had forgotton to apply the scale before adding the cloth etc.
